# React Router V4 - Can't get URL params in props

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to create simple React-Redux-Router V4 app. The route to one of my components makes use of the url param. In my `Route` components, I've been passing in the `render` prop, which is an anonymous function that returns a component. Like so:

`<Route key="post" path="/post/:id" render={() => <Post/>} />`

I use this prop as opposed to the `component` prop:

`<Route key="post" path="/post/:id" component={Post} />`

Because I'm not able to props into the rendered component using the `component` prop. The issue is, with the `component` prop, you can make use of `props.match.params.name`, which will contain the exact param I need. This is not available when using the `render` component.

I can use `window.location.href` but it feels dirty.

Thanks!

Comment: *"Because I'm not able to props in the rendered component using the `component` prop"* - it's unclear what the problem is with the `component` prop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Js setState with params when onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521244/react-js-setstate-with-params-when-onclick)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `match`, `location`, and `history` props are passed into your `render` function.

Example:

```
<Route key="post" path="/post/:id" render={({ match }) => <Post name={match.params.name}/>} />
```

Documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-props

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to import this first**

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

After that at the end export the component like this. 'User' is a class component name

```
export default (withRouter(User));
```

Now, If you will print the value you will get a response.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('Props', this.props);
    }
```

Happy Coding